# How do I change what is shown for each record in the left column of the CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: icloud, dashboard, cloudkit

[image: Image from Apple Documentation]

As you can see above, Apple is showing the "title" field in the left column even though the address field is listed first (it annoyingly lists everything in alphabetical order). How did they do this? Mine always lists the first field in the left hand side which makes it very hard to quickly find a record at a glance.

[image: My CloudKit Dashboard backend]

My backend forces me to only see completedBy which has no info in it right now so it just shows No Name. How do I make it show the task name in that left hand column?

Comment: You answered your own question almost. Try deleting the record definition evening, taking a snapshot before you do before you do and then recreate it i the morning with the field you want to appear on the left as the first field in the record. I suggest you do it over night to give the Apple farm behind this time to sort itself out, giving you making such a minor change.

Comment: this answer confuses me. How did I answer my own question? The top image is a stock image from apple as part of their documentation. The bottom image is my backend. Why would deleting a record make it change the way it appears?

Answer (score 1):

Michael, Did a few experiments, the fields appear in alphabetical order it seems, not in the order you create them; so if you want them to appear in the dashboard in a particular order than you can put a force sorting character into the name. Like this...

[image]

It not ideal I agree and doesn't ultimately make sense; your not going to be using the dashboard for much more than debugging, surely. But I don't know maybe there is a method in your madness as they say.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a field called `Title`, `title`, `Name`, or `name` it uses that.  Otherwise, it takes the first string field of the alphabetically sorted field list.